# Understanding model in djangorestframwork unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I was reading unit test for filters in [django-rest-framework](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e10d32fb122619a7977909536b642d09603192a/tests/test_filters.py#L202). I tried to mock the unit test locally in another project by adding a model as above but my tests fail with: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_post" does not exist`.

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import filters, serializers


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    content  = models.TextField(max_length=255)

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'

class TestPostFilter(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Post.objects.create(title="A post title",content="some post content")

    def test_search(self):
        assert True
```

I understand that to create a corresponding db table for a model we have to run `./manage.py makemigrations blog` and `./manage.py migrate blog`, but the [example](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e10d32fb122619a7977909536b642d09603192a/tests/test_filters.py#L202) above is adding a dummy model only for testing purpose. I dont see how for that model migrations are executed. Probably lots of going on in the background. My question is how this model is being created in test database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the `tests` package, it is being setup as a Django app. Notice the `models.py` in `tests`, and most important the `def pytest_configure(configure)` function in the `conftest.py` file. You will need to do the same in order to have models defined for the test environment.

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e10d32fb122619a7977909536b642d09603192a/tests/models.py
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0e10d32fb122619a7977909536b642d09603192a/tests/conftest.py